# Does Tk provide support for Wayland display protocol?

Tags: tk-toolkit, wayland

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIctzAQOe44) introduced to me the issues with X and it's replacement by the Wayland protocol. The adoption of the Wayland protocol appears to be growing over the years.

My questions:

1. Is tkinter and tcl/Tk going to comply with the Wayland protocol? If so, when is it expected to happen? Has it happened already? What is the roadmap?
2. How will tkinter programming change with the use of the Wayland Display protocol?

Comment: I, for one, did not yet hear of any work done to directly implement Wayland support in Tk (I may be completely wrong though). Still, given the number of "legacy" programs written to speak the X Window protocol, any sensible Wayland implementation will suppsedly provide [XWayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html) as well to handle them.

Answer (score 3):

The undroidwish project appears to have ported Tcl/Tk to Wayland, via SDL2's support for it, in early 2017. undroidwish is a variant of AndroWish, a port of Tcl/Tk to Android. It's mentioned on the [tcl.tk wiki](https://wiki.tcl.tk/668) (and other places on that wiki).

Although a Wayland port was raised as a [possibility for the GSoC 2016](https://wiki.tcl.tk/28079), it doesn't appear to have been implemented as part of upstream.

There's nothing I've found to indicate that Tcl/Tk coding is different per se, though  X11 calls will be unavailable for a Wayland-based application just as with, say, [GTK3](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Wayland#GTK).