# Git-Gui / Gitk Broken interface cause crash on kde plasma wayland

Tags: kde-plasma, wayland, git-gui, gitk

#### Context

Few months ago (I don't remember a specific cause), the gitk UI starts showing a strange behavior. 80% of the time, when I start the app in a repository it will display a broken interface. And if I restart gitk few times, the wayland session will crash (Actually I'm not sure about that, I am still logged in).
Besides, everything works fine with the desktop environment.

#### Flow

1. Login-in plasma wayland, no error to this point, every app is looking god, no crashes.
2. Opening gitk/git-gui in a repository folder (Any one).
3. Usually, it doesn't crash the first time, it only shows a broken interface (See picture).
4. Closing and restarting the app in the same folder.
5. Gitk does not start, the screen become black for 1sec, and the wayland session is restarted.
6. All previously opened apps are closed but we are still logged-in, a `Akonadi server crash` notification appears.

#### Trials and failures

- Currently I have `gitk-2.41.0-1.fc37.noarch` installed, but I also tried with `gitk-2.37.3-1.fc37.noarch` (+ all related git packages).
- I tried to unset all `gui.geometry` values in config.
- I installed `unifont` (don't remember if it was already here).
- Of courses it crashes in every repository, with any history.
- I changed the fonts used be gitk, same behavior.

#### Logs and config

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nccUsejc) to `sudo journalctl -rxp 3 --since {crash}`

```
> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 37 (Thirty Seven)
Release:    37
Codename:   ThirtySeven
```

```
> lspci -v
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8537
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

...
```

[image]

[image: Broken UI]

Comment: If I understood correctly, StackOverflow is for asking programming questions. This question should be in a KDE dedicated forum. Not sure if there is one on stackexchange, but superuser would fit better. Or even the kde subreddit.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem, also on KDE 5.27 on Wayland. Could you open an issue on https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues and on https://bugs.kde.org/ too? You've gathered a lot of debug information, it's a complete bug report.

Comment: Gitk is using tcl/tk, which doesn't support Wayland. More (old) details on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065046/does-tk-provide-support-for-wayland-display-protocol, but little help. As much as gitk was fast and convenient, I'll start looking for something more modern.